# i cannot migrate in Laravel, i am using windows

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
D:\laravel\internProject1>php artisan migrate

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = crud and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

Comment: did you configure your .env?

Comment: did you set database config in .env file?

Comment: You have to setup your database connection in `.env` file

Comment: This question needs a [mcve].

Comment: .env is configured properly, it says could not find driver
[D:\laravel\project\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")]

Answer (score 1):

I think your php_pdo_mysql.dll extension is missing.

as you're on Windows make it by simply uncomment the extension in your php.ini configuration file

```
;extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
```

Comment: i cannot find such extension on php.ini